# View mysql in phalcon

Tags: mysql, view, phalcon

How to call a view mysql from phalcon 
I'm doing this in my phalcon controller:

```
$phql = "select id,description,name,dni from ViewUser where name like '%mark%' ";

$usuario = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

Apparently I'm getting an error processing the where, why if yo process this:

```
$phql = "select id,description,name,dni from ViewUser";

$usuario = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

I no longer get error.
For the call of the view, already create my model ViewUser. 
I do not know what is wrong when I put the conditions in the WHERE.

Any help is welcome. Thank.

Comment: Can you show us the error you are getting?

Comment: If you have a model, why don't you try query builder, and in query builder ->where("name LIKE :name:")
->bind("name" => "%mark%")
does this help you?